# cordova-imagePickerで画像を表示・選択する方法

Tags: monaca, cordova

お世話になります。タイトルで書いたことをやりたいのですがエラーが発生します。
最初から順に書きますので漏れなどあればご教示ください。

Monacaを使用しています。

1.新規プロジェクトから「Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート(ユニバーサルアプリ対応版)」を選択
2.「ファイル」-「Cordavaプラグインの管理」から「Cordovaプラグインのインポート」をクリック
3.「ZIP形式のプラグイン」を選んで、[配布元](https://github.com/ch000/cordova-imagePicker)から落としたZipをインポート
インポート結果が下記画像になります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

4.index.htmlのscript内を下記に変更

```
    <script>
    ons.bootstrap();
    if(typeof device === 'undefined'){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }else{
        onDeviceReady();
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
    try{
        window.imagePicker.getPictures(
            function(results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            }
        );
    } catch(e){
        alert(e);

    }
    }
</script>
```

IOS9.3でMonacaデバッガーから起動すると下記エラーが発生
「TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPictures' of undefined」
カメラプラグインを有効にすると
「TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.imagePicker.getPictures')」となります。

追記：
DeviceプラグインとinAppBrowserプラグインも追加しております。

Comment: `if(typeof device === 'undefined')` この条件式、逆ではないですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。逆とはどういう事でしょうか？変数のデータ型チェックを意図しております。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

冒頭のif文でdevicereadyが発火済みかどうかチェックしているのだと推測しますが、window.deviceが存在することはdevicereadyが完了していることを保証しません。したがってdevicereadyイベントの発火前にonDeviceReady()関数が呼ばれたためにエラーになっているのでしょう。
また、

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

で登録された関数はdevicereadyが既に発火済みの場合は即時実行されますので

```
if(typeof device === 'undefined'){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}else{
    onDeviceReady();
}
```

この部分は

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

これで十分です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。if文を外して一行にしました。まだ同じエラーが発生しているのでonDeviceReady内でalert(window.imagePicker);を実行したところundefinedが返ってきます。

Comment: ひょっとして通常版のmonacaデバッガーを使っていますか？外部プラグインを追加する場合、カスタムビルド版のデバッガーを利用してください。http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/dependencies/custom_cordova_plugin/#debugger-for-custom-plugins

Comment: デバッグビルドでapkを作って試しても症状が同じなのです。カスタムビルド版のデバッガーを試します。

Comment: @ShinjiHorie プラグインの配布元として記載されているのはforkリポジトリのようですが、fork元の最新版では試してみましたか？

Comment: Fork元にプラグインを差し替えてapk作成して試した結果、ImageURIを返してくれました。サポートありがとうございました！

Comment: @ShinjiHorie 解決したようでしたら、この質問が解決済みであることを示すために[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をお願いします。